# Sum attributes of relation tables after performing division to them

Tags: laravel, aggregate, laravel-5.6, laravel-query-builder

I couldn't come up with an appropriate title, excuse me for which.
The situation is the following:

I've got two tables: `montages` and `orders`, where `Montage` belongs to `Order`.
My goal is to build a single mysql query which to return a single float value to represent a sum of values for multiple montages. For each montage in the query I need to divide the budget of its order by the number of montages which belong to the same order. The result of this division should be an attribute of ecah montage. Finally, I want to sum those attributes and retrieve a single value.

I've tried a lot of variation of something like the following, but none seemed to be written in correct syntax, so I kept getting errors:

```
$sum = App\Montage::where(/*this doesn't matter*/)
->join('orders', 'montages.order_id', '=', 'orders.id') //join the orders table
->select('montages.*, orders.budget') //include the budget column
->selectRaw('count(* where order_id = order_id) as all') //count all the montages of the same order and assing that count to the current montage
->selectRaw('(orders.budget / all) as daily_payment') //divide the budget of the order by the count; store the result as `daily_payment`
->sum('daily_payment') //sum the daily payments
```

I'm really lost with the proper syntax and can't figure it out. I'd estimate that to be a rather trivial sql task for people who know their stuff, but unfortunately I don't seem to be one of them... Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you take a look at the [withCount()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) method in Laravel? Might be useful for you.

Comment: That's for sure a cool utility I wasn't aware of, but could I implement it in the query somehow and then proceed with the returned count? Could you build an example?

Comment: @DeesOomens The problem with that is I don't want to retrieve the collection of models then, I only need that single value after performing the mentioned actions to the attributes and the aggregate.